# Join is not working in MY SQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.fname,
s.description FROM customer c  INNER JOIN orders o ON c.customer_num =
o.customer_num INNER JOIN items i ON o.order_num = i.order_num INNER
JOIN stock s on s.stock_num = i.stock_num WHERE i.manu_code = 'ANZ';
```

Comment: where is the question, error you get, table structure, sample data?

Comment: post your tables schema

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by `not working` ? What is the inputs / what is the result you are expecting / what is the result you are actually getting?

Comment: i have one field also common between customer and orders table how to join that field @AnandSKumar

Comment: without making other alias of any one table how to join cust_id field that is also common between customers and orders table . @AnandSKumar

Comment: Do you mean you have there are two different relationships betweenn customer and order and you want to include both in the query?

Comment: when `o.customer_num = c.customer_num` would `o.cust_id = c.cust_id` as well ? Or would they be different , if different you will need to use different aliases

Comment: actually i am working in jtable after making more alias query is executing in 35 seconds .and jtable is loading very slowly

Answer (score 2):

I'm very confident that `JOIN` is "working" in MySQL.

(I could add here an example that demonstrates that it works.)

---

**EDIT**

If you have two or columns "in common" between two tables, and you want to reference both columns in an equality comparisons in a join predicate, just add `AND col2 = col2` to the existing `ON` clause...

For example, to add the condition that `cust_id` is equal between `customer` and `orders`

```
  SELECT DISTINCT c.fname
       , s.description
    FROM customer c
    JOIN orders o 
      ON o.customer_num = c.customer_num
     AND o.cust_id      = c.cust_id
  -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        add this line
    JOIN items i 
      ON i.order_num = o.order_num
    JOIN stock s
      ON s.stock_num = i.stock_num
   WHERE i.manu_code = 'ANZ';
```

If you want to join between `customer` and `orders` on *either* `customer_num` or `cust_id`, you can replace the `AND` with `OR`. (But this is an odd pattern, having two different columns to match on; this is not the normative pattern.)

Comment: Hey join in my  case is working but i have to join one more field that is also common between customers and orders table . so how to join that part without making any more alias of table.